# Slang or scientific term for "mental food"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

By saying "mental food" I mean something that you enjoy digesting mentally, like watching a football game or reading a comic book.
(It is in contrast to "physical food" which you physically eating the food).
For example:

> Asian U23 football championship is the "____________" for Vietnamese people.

Comment: food for the mind, food for the soul, food for the body, not mental food unless you want to sound literary.

Comment: Not an answer because it is related but not exact, but something one enjoys looking at or listening to can be referred to as *eye candy* or *ear candy*.

Comment: 'mental' has a slight connotation of 'intellectual', so 'mental food' sounds very strange in English for sports topics.

Comment: Cerebral nourishment.

Comment: Mental grist is technically food (ground corn or malt) but is usually a lot more serious. Pap is a lot less serious, but to the point of triviality.

Comment: Are you asking about something that's serious or something that's trivial? I'm also not sure why you have rejected *mental food*. Would *brain food* be better? Or are you looking for something specifically different?

Comment: Why not just stick with the base metaphor 'preferred diet [of]'.

Comment: "mental food" or "food for the mind" or "intellectual nourishment" or anything like that suggests something involving significant mental effort, learning, and personal improvement, while watching sports or superhero films, playing video games, etc, is generally viewed as entertainment, recreation, relaxation, or "switching off your brain".

Comment: I'm fairly sure that whatever fits in your space, the following preposition will be "of", not for, if you keep the definite article before it: compare "food for thought" and "the opium of the masses". (The latter fits comic books quite well, I think.)

Answer (score 1):

A term for an item of mental interest is "Food for thought" but that would be only a mouthful, not a meal's worth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather surprised no one has yet suggested this potential candidate: **Pabulum**

> Intellectual material that is bland, trite, or insipid; *pablum*:

*"TV ... gobbled up comedy material and spat it out as pabulum" (Richard Corliss)*

[pabulum](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pabulum)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **intellectual nourishment**.

It is defined on [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/intellectual+nourishment) as,

> anything that provides mental stimulus for thinking; food for thought.

---

Note: If you get entertained by some insipid subject: Mathematics documentaries, or some abstract subject etc. (which people normally find tasteless), then there is a word for it.

Pabulum or pablum (noun)
Oxford defines it as,
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pabulum

> Bland or insipid intellectual matter, entertainment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It did not seem to me that football is an activity appreciated from an intellectual standpoint.  But, thanks to your posing the question, I found a good article in The Irish Times: 'The rise of the Football Intellectual', article by Ian Maleney, Wed. Nov 9, 2016.  In it, Maleney references several authors on the subject.

But back to your question. First: Does, in fact, the **entire** (or nearly so in your estimation), populace of Vietnam enjoy football.  "Asian U23 football championship is the "____________" for Vietnamese people." Increasingly, we are told "we all" - when "we all" most certainly do not - for example, have electronic devices.

As to "comic books" - it would depend on the style of comic book, yes?  A comic book, like food, can primarily be a visual treat, if you will.  Or, it can be to instruct, etc.  Or, both.  There have been literary comic books, for certain.

"Fodder" is used by the British for what you call "mental food."  "Feast" doesn't apply.

How about referencing a literary work you reasonably believe to be known by your target population.

"Asian U23 football championship is the "____________" for Vietnamese people.

Or, make it personal.  What is it about football that stimulates you intellectually, and what is your food/book that applies.

Answer (score 0):

**Mental snacks**

There is a book titled ["Mental snacks: Nourishment for your mind and fuel for your life!"](https://juliomelara.com/books/mental-snacks). There is also this sentence from a [book review](https://www.dispatch.com/article/20150508/ENTERTAINMENT/305089646) of "How to bake pi: Higher math served in bit-sized chunks",

> As a whole, the book is hard to absorb in a few sittings; it is better
>   spaced out as mental snacks than attempted as one long feast. But it
>   offers enough nourishment for the brain to chew on for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

**brain food**, *U.S.,* (a) intellectual sustenance; something which stimulates thought or creativity; (b) food believed to be beneficial to the brain, esp. in increasing intellectual power.

From the OED
[image: Definition and quotations for "Brain Food"]